# Rename Woo-commerce Product Tab

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have used this to rename the description tab into "More Information"

but it will not work, what do I wrong?

I use Woocommerce Version 3.4.3 with Booking extension

```
    <?php
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_customize_tabs', 100, 1 
 );
 function woo_customize_tabs( $tabs ) {

 unset($tabs['reviews']);    // Remove the reviews tab

 $tabs['description']['title'] = __( 'More Information' ); // Rename the 
 description tab

 return $tabs;
 }
```

Comment: I have tested your code and it just work perfectly on Woocommerce 3.4.x (last version). You need to add this code in the  function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). May be `<?php` is not needed at start.